# Writing an API to query multiple databases

Tags: java, api, dropwizard, nosql

If I'm building a system which has various, usually but not limited to NoSQL, databases I want to query across - different databases for different purposes; text search, geo, graph, etc.

On top of it I've got an API (currently JAX-RS returning JSON, sitting on dropwizard and I need to stick to something that will work on a Java stack) which at the moment allows a UI to query each source independently.

However, I'd like to allow the UI to be able to query along the lines of *show me a graph of the top 10 users and their first degree connections who have records matching the term cheese OR wine in Italy AND Greece*.

I'm not sure what the route of least resistance is to do this - I'd hope to avoid writing a new generic query language myself, obviously. I've spotted https://orchestrate.io/ but I need to stick to open source. Any suggestions?